Android Studio Iguana Download Sources Failed
Imagine I used coil compose in my project, when I want to see the library document I navigate to source code and click Download sources button( see image below ):


but Download fails and gradle print out this message:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Initialization script '/private/var/folders/d7/g44k209s12g2b15zz4nlzyk40000gn/T/ijmiscinit7.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':feature:home:view:implementation:DownloadSources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':feature:home:view:implementation:downloadSources_238f4792-5185-455f-a47d-8db753dda73e'.
   > Could not find io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.6.0@aar.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/coil-kt/coil-compose/2.6.0@aar/coil-compose-2.6.0@aar.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/coil-kt/coil-compose/2.6.0@aar/coil-compose-2.6.0@aar.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/io/coil-kt/coil-compose/2.6.0@aar/coil-compose-2.6.0@aar.pom
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/io/coil-kt/coil-compose/2.6.0@aar/coil-compose-2.6.0@aar.pom
     Required by:
         project :feature:home:view:implementation


I use this distribution of grade: 
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip

I'm using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1

For me, deleting .gradle folder from users/neckoee/.gradle and building project again did the trick!

any one find that solution ??
